# Installing Windows in GPT Partition Style

Tags: mbr, windows-installation, gpt

Recently, I received three laptops from my family members for installing Windows.

In one laptop, Windows 10 is installed with one volume i.e. C: and with data (like files, images, video, etc). And C: is GPT partition style.

In second laptop, there is one volume i.e. C: with data (like files, images, video, etc).  C: is GPT partition style. And the error message on screen is “Operating System not found”.  And

In third laptop, there are three volumes (C:, D: and E:) with GPT partition style. Data (like files, images, video, etc) are in both volumes (D: and E:). And the error message on screen is “Operating System not found”.

I have to install Windows 7 in all three laptops without losing data.

I have two bootable USB sticks created by Rufus. One is with MBR Partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI. And another is GPT partition scheme for UEFI. I am not able install Windows with any sticks.

I have gone through some web links but not useful.

Irrespective of manufacturer and modal number, how to install Windows in all three laptops?

Regards

InTech

Comment: "I have to install Windows 7 in all three laptops without losing data." - Mount the HDD to a fourth computer, backup your data, because there is no way to downgrade to Windows 7 without risking your data on the system partition.  'how to install Windows in all three laptops?" - Download ISO, burn bootable media, install Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to directly downgrade from Windows 10 (assuming even computer 2 and computer 3 are) to Windows 7.

Backup your data *the old way*, then make sure laptops are in EFI mode (because without hacks you need that to boot from GPT) and format disk before installation.

Comment: Windows 10 fully supports `Legacy Mode/CPM/Compatability Mode` it just requires you to use MBR instead of GPT.

Comment: ?? OP is asking for some way to install W7 over his W10 partition. For some reason, he thinks the problem with installation procedure is with partition table scheme _instead of the w10->w7 passage_